# Oracle stored procedure migration to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

How to migrate this part of Oracle stored procedure

```
FOR t IN (WITH temp_transaction(str) AS (SELECT i_transaction_id FROM dual)
```

to a PostgreSQL function?

```
Procedure sp_update
(
 i_mem_id IN WLVENDOR.REWARD_TRX_DETAIL.WL_MEM_ID%TYPE,
 i_rebate_detail_id  IN WLVENDOR.REWARD_TRX_DETAIL.WL_REBATE_DETAIL_ID%TYPE,
 i_transaction_id IN VARCHAR,
 i_limit_days IN NUMBER,
 o_rows_affected OUT NUMBER
)
IS
    err_msg   VARCHAR(500);
  BEGIN
   FOR t IN (WITH temp_transaction(str) AS (
     SELECT i_transaction_id FROM dual
   )
   SELECT CAST(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) as Number) transactionId
   FROM temp_transaction
   CONNECT BY regexp_substr(str, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level) is not null) LOOP
    // UPDATE Statement
    END LOOP;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into o_rows_affected FROM WLVENDOR.REWARD_TRX_DETAIL WHERE wl_rebate_detail_id = i_rebate_detail_id;

END sp_update;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the select query is used in oracle to split a comma separated string into rows.

In Postgres, there is a technique using `string_to_array` to convert it to array and `unnest` function to transform them to rows.

For your case, you may loop through the array itself with `FOREACH`

So, your procedure( postgres function would look something like

```
create or replace function sp_update
..  --other 
..  --statements

DECLARE
    transactionId   numeric;
    ..--other declarations.
  BEGIN
   FOREACH transactionId IN ARRAY string_to_array(i_transaction_id,',')::numeric[] as
    LOOP
    -- UPDATE Statement
    END LOOP;
  .. --other statements
  ..
END $$;
```

A recommended alternative would be pass an `ARRAY` of multiple ids instead of sending comma separated `i_transaction_id`. Also, try to convert the update query to be able to run as **single** statement rather than use a loop.

Comment: `unnest()` isn't needed in PL/pgSQL. You can iterate over an array directly using `foreach`

Comment: Hi Kaushik ,Thanks for your quick response ,it's working fine.